# Is my idea of incoming/outgoing arcs correct?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, optimization, network-flow

I'm reading Jungnickel's *Graphs, Networks and Algorithms*. I've met the following lemma:

> [image]

I know that $e^{-}$ are the incoming vertices and $e^{+}$ are the outgoing vertices. Then I've tried to draw a digraph to see the result of the lemma, I've made the following digraph:

$$\begin{matrix}
{sa(10)}&{ba(10)}&{db(5)}&{ac(9)}&{ca(6)}\\ 
{sb(7)}&{bd(7)}&{da(8)}&{}&{cd(4)}\\ 
{}&{}&{dt(10)}&{}&{ct(5)}
\end{matrix}$$

So, what is the sum of the value of the flow of the outgoing arc? How to know what is an outgoing arc? My guess is that if you take $bd$ to be and outgoing arc, then $db$ is the incoming arc.

Also, when doing the sum in the lemma, when I have an arc $da$ and don't have $ad$, then it would be the sum of the value of the flow of $da$ minus the sum of the value of the flow of the arc $ad$ and if it does not exist, then $f(ad)=0.$ Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from your question, I think you may be misinterpreting the sums. From left to right, you're summing over:

- The arcs that have "s" as their tail
- The arcs that have "s" as their head
- The arcs that have "t" as their head
- The arcs that have "t" as their tail.

In particular, the sums in the lemma do not involve any arcs that are not incident to s or t. Think of the left side of the equation as "net flow leaving $s$" and the right side as "net flow entering $t$".

Comment: Is it okay to have arcs with $s$ as their head? Until now, I have a little impression that such thing is not not possible (given the examples I've seen in my lectures).

Comment: Yes, Jungnickel's definition of a flow network permits that. It would be somewhat silly to *use* those arcs if you're trying to make a maximum $s,t$-flow, which is probably why they don't show up in many examples, but they're allowed to be in the graph.